# Can we use FPU in an interrupt context?

Tags: linux-kernel, fpu

Using FPU in Linux kernel supposes that FPU block encloses with `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` functions. The first one looks like this:

```
 41 static inline void kernel_fpu_begin(void)
 42 {
 43         WARN_ON_ONCE(!irq_fpu_usable());
 44         preempt_disable();
 45         __kernel_fpu_begin();
 46 }
```

Kernel issues a warning if FPU can't be usable because of:

```
 64 bool irq_fpu_usable(void)
 65 {
 66         return !in_interrupt() ||
 67                 interrupted_user_mode() ||
 68                 interrupted_kernel_fpu_idle();
 69 }
 70 EXPORT_SYMBOL(irq_fpu_usable);
```

So, am I right that we can't use FPU in interrupt context?

And if it is I want to know why we can't?

Comment: You *can* use FPU in interrupt context, but only if you interrupted a user mode program or if you interrupted some kernel code that did not use the FPU.

Comment: @CL. Does it means that I can't use FPU in `softIRQ` context (in `net_rx_action`, for ex.)?

Comment: The restrictions above make no difference between hard and soft interrupt context.

Comment: @CL. Just for the final clarification. I have no chances to run FPU-based code within the softIRQ context, right?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel has only one place to save the FPU state, so it is not allowed to have kernel FPU code that interrupts other kernel FPU code.

The `irq_fpu_usable` function prints a warning only for kernel FPU code that *actually* is interrupting other kernel FPU code, but in practice, it is not possible to control when your interrupt runs.

Therefore, using FPU in interrupt context is not really possible.
(It does not make sense either, because FPU code is useful only as a performance optimization, and interrupts should never run for so long that such optimizations are needed.)